# Node cache doesn't fire the "on expired" callback as intended

Tags: node.js, caching

I'm trying to use node cache's "on expired" event to pull latest data as and when the TTL for the cache key value pair ends. 
My understanding is it should get called immediately when the cache expires but I think it doesn't gets called until check period ends and the cache cleans up the expired values. Is that so or I'm doing something wrong?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache#expired

Answer (score 6):

By default, node-cache will not periodically check for expired keys and thus the on expired event will only trigger once the key is accessed. You can change this behavior by setting the `checkperiod` option when creating node-cache.

```
checkperiod: (default: 600) The period in seconds, as a number, used for the automatic delete check interval. 0 = no periodic check.
```

```
const NodeCache = require( "node-cache" );
const myCache = new NodeCache({ checkperiod: 120 }); // will check every 120 seconds
```

[Link the doc explaining this.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache#options)

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to achieve this. My experience was following, as you described:

> My understanding is it should get called immediately when the cache
>   expires but I think it doesn't gets called until check period ends and
>   the cache cleans up the expired values

Comment: I don't know for sure if enableLegacyCallbacks under https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache#options has any effect on this. My objective was to refresh the cache after a time period. So I took help of has (Key) function coupled with some cron implementation on node to refresh the cache.